# how query by column number with awk

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

I would like to get time difference by column number 2 delimited by `,` for below command. It works fine by default for the first column.

table:

```
20220505,12:00:12,user,dept
20220505,12:00:25,user,dept
20220505,12:00:32,user,dept
```

command:

```
awk -F: '{t=$1*3600+$2*60+$3} NR>1{printf( "%.6f\n", t-p)}{p=t}' inputfile
```

I tried: but failed to get correct result.

```
awk -F ',' $2 '{t=$1*3600+$2*60+$3} NR>1{printf( "%.6f\n", t-p)}{p=t}' inputfile
```

Comment: When asking **time delta** related question, two underlying aspects are paramount: **(1)** your time zone and whether DST is in effect, **(2)** whether the system on which those time stamps were generated is the same as that where time deltas are to be computed. This is because each may modify results of time delta computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell awk to use **both** `,` and `:` as field separators.  Note that this will change the numbering of the fields (because both field separators are applied to each input line). For example:

```
$ awk -F '[:,]' '{ t = $2*3600 + $3*60 + $4 }
                 NR > 1 { printf "%.6f\n", t-p }
                 { p=t }' inputfile
13.000000
7.000000
```

Note that this does not calculate time differences across different days.  To do that, you'd need to parse the combined date and time into a `time_t` value (i.e. seconds since the epoch, Midnight on Jan 1 1970).  For example, with **GNU** awk, using the `mktime()` function:

```
$ awk -F '[:,]' '{
                    # extract the year, month, and day from the first field
                    y = substr($1,1,4);
                    m = substr($1,5,2);
                    d = substr($1,7,2);
                    # create a space-separated datespec string, combining y,m,d with
                    # hours, minutes, and seconds from fields 2, 3, and 4
                    datespec = y " " m " " d " " $2 " " $3 " " $4;
                    # convert it to seconds since the epoch
                    t = mktime(datespec)
                  }
                  NR > 1 { printf "%.6f\n", t-p }
                  { p=t }' inputfile
13.000000
7.000000
```

Run `man awk` and search for `mktime` for a summary on how this function works.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.split(",");  my @b; for ^@a.elems -> $i {  \
         my $date = @a[$i][0].subst(/ ^ (\d**4)(\d**2)(\d**2) $/, {"$0-$1-$2"});  \
         @b.push: "{$date}T@a[$i][1]Z".DateTime.Instant };  \
         loop (my $i = 0; $i < @b.elems-1; $i++) { put @b[$i+1] - @b[$i] };'
```

Raku handles dates and times using the `ISO 8601` *interchange standard*, built-in. In the first statement, `lines` are read in, each `split` on `","` commas, and saved in `@a` array. Array `@b` is declared. Then lines are looped over, with elements of the first column (dates) being `subst` such that a `-` hyphen separated `$date` is created, and this string is used to generate an ISO 8601 `DateTime` like `2022-05-05T12:00:12Z`. This `DateTime` is immediately converted to an `Instant` object (in seconds) that is `push`ed onto the `@b` array. In the final statement, `Instant` seconds are `loop`ed over, and subtracted from each other.

Sample Input 1:

```
20220505,12:00:12,user,dept
20220505,12:00:25,user,dept
20220505,12:00:32,user,dept
```

Sample Output 1:

```
13
7
```

Below the advantage of using `ISO 8601` dates and times: timestamps that cross from one date to the next are properly handled.

Sample Input 2:

```
20220505,23:59:45,user,dept
20220506,00:00:00,user,dept
20220506,00:00:15,user,dept
```

Sample Output 2:

```
15
15
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
https://docs.raku.org/language/temporal#index-entry-Date_and_time_functions
https://raku.org